# streamlit selectbox on sidebar not working

Tags: python, streamlit

selectbox on sidebar in streamlit only display the label caption. it doesnt display the drop down menu with the values but if I modify the code and remove 'sidebar', it works fine on the main page.

example:

```
st.sidebar.selectbox('select stock',['APPL', 'GOOG'])
```

will only display 'select stock' on the sidebar without the drop-down menu but

```
st.selectbox('select stock',['APPL', 'GOOG'])
```

will work fine on the main page

why is this?

Comment: It works using the `with st.sidebar:` notation in streamlit 1.9, does that work with your version?

Comment: What is your streamlit version?

Comment: `st.sidebar.selectbox` should work with the latest version.

Comment: streamlit 1.12.2 is the version. I believe this is the most recent version because i ran 'pip install --upgrade streamlit' before  noticing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

uninstalling and reinstalling streamlit fixed the issue!